# Compare Time to Document Interval and Update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Use Case:**

I've got a mongodb collection with a couple million documents. Documents in this 
collection must be updated sometimes. Therefore I've setup a `monitorFrequency` field which would define the that a specific document must be updated every 6, 12, 24 or 720 hours. Additionally I setup a field called `lastRefreshAt` which is a timestamp of the last actual update.

**The problem:**

1. How can I select all documents from my collection `profiles` which need to be refreshed again (because monitorFrequency is older than lastRefreshAt).
2. Should I run that on a single query which would only return those documents which need to be refreshed again or should I rather iterate on all documents with a cursor and check in my node application if the document needs to be refreshed or not?

I would know how to do approach #2, but I am not sure what approach to chose and how the query for #1 would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches depending on available architecture and choices. Some are good choices and some are bad, but we might as well explain them all.

#### Use $where with multi-update

As a first option to examine, you could use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to calculate the difference for selection and feed directly to [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) or [`.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) for that matter:

```
db.profiles.update(
  {
    "$where": function() {
      return (Date.now() - this.lastRefreshAt.valueOf())
        > ( this.monitorFrequency * 1000 * 60 * 60 );
    }
  },
  { "$currentDate": { "lastRefreshAt": true } },
  { "multi": true } 
)
```

Which pretty simply works out the milliseconds difference between the current `"lastRefreshAt"` value and the current `Date` value and compares that to the stored `"monitorFrequency"` converted into milliseconds itself.

The [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) is appplied because it is a [`"multi"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) update and applied to all matched documents, so this ensures the "server timestamp" at the actual time of document update is applied to the document.

It's not fantastic as it does require a full collection scan in order to select the documents via calculation and thus cannot use an index. Plus it's JavaScript evaluation, which not being native code does add some overhead.

#### Loop the matched selection

So JavaScript is not that great a selection option in general when other options apply. Instead try using the aggregation framework for the calculation and loop the cursor result:

```
var ops = [];

db.profiles.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$subtract": [new Date(), "$lastRefreshAt"] },
          { "$multiply": ["$monitorFrequency", 1000 * 60 * 60] }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$currentDate": { "lastRefreshAt": true } }
    }
  });

  if ( ops.length > 1000 ) {
    db.profiles.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.profiles.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

So again that's a collection scan due to the calculation but it is done with native operators, so that part at least should be a bit faster. Also from a technical standpoint it's a little different because the `new Date()` is actually established at the time of request and not per document iterated as it would be using `$where`. Lacking an operator to produce the "current date" internally, there is no way for the aggregation framework to do this per iteration.

And of course, instead of just applying our "update" expression as it matches documents, we are looping the result cursor and applying a function. So whilst there are "some" gains, there is also additional overhead. Mileage may vary as to performance and practicality.

#### Parallel Updates

Personally I would do neither of the above and simply run a query selecting each marked `"monitorFrequency"` and looking for the dates between the boundaries that exceed the allowed difference.

As a simple example using NodeJS to implement [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for parallel calls:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const onHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;

(async function() {

  let db;

  try {

    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    let collection = db.collection('profiles');

    let intervals = [6, 12, 24, 720];

    let snapDate = new Date();

    await Promise.all(
      intervals.map( (monitorFrequency,i) =>
        collection.updateMany(
          {
            monitorFrequency,
            "lastRefreshAt": Object.assign(
              { "$lt": new Date(snapDate.valueOf() - intervals[i] * oneHour) },
              (i < intervals.length) ?
                { "$gt": new Date(snapDate.valueOf() - intervals[i+1] * oneHour) }
                : {}
            )
          },
          { "$currentDate": { "lastRefreshAt": true } },
        )
      )
    );

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

This would allow you to index on the two fields and allow optimal selection, and since the "date ranges" are paired to their calculated difference from `"monitorFrequency"` then those documents that "require refresh" are the only ones that get selected for update.

Gievn the finite number of possible intervals this is what I would suspect to be the most optimal solution. But the construction along with the fact that the actual `"update"` portion remains consistent for each selection leads to one other option.

#### Use $or for each selection.

Much the same logic as above, but instead applied to build an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition for the "query" portion of a "single" update. It is an "array of criteria" afterall, which is essentially the same as an "array of queries" which is what we are doing above. So just turn it around a little:

```
let intervals = [6, 12, 24, 720];
let snapDate = new Date();

db.profiles.updateMany(
  { 
    "$or": intervals.map( (monitorFrequency,i) =>
      ({
        monitorFrequency,
        "lastRefreshAt": Object.assign(
          { "$lt": new Date(snapDate.valueOf() - intervals[i] * oneHour) },
          (i < intervals.length) ?
            { "$gt": new Date(snapDate.valueOf() - intervals[i+1] * oneHour) }
            : {}
        )
      })
    )
  },
  { "$currentDate": { "lastRefreshAt": true } }
)
```

This then becomes one simple statement and of course can actually use indexes where available. Generally this is what you should be doing, though as I have suggested my intuition tells me that 4 threads of execution constrained only by the slowest one gets the job done slightly faster. Again, mileage may vary on that but logic dictates that this is so.

---

So the basic lesson here is "whilst you may think" that the logical approach is to calculate the values and compare within the database itself, it's actually the worst possible thing you can do for query performance.

The simple approach taken are to work out the criteria that should select the documents you want "before" you issue the query statement to the server. This means you are looking at "concrete values" rather than "calculation results" in comparison. And "concrete values" can actually be indexed, which is generally what you want for database queries.